# Add K3s agent to server in a docker container (using Tailscale userspace networking)

Tags: docker, kubernetes, k3s

I have a K3s server running somewhere, connected to Tailscale. I am able to connect regular VM agents to it via Tailscale under normal circumstances. However, I also need to add an agent "node" that is actually running in a docker container.

For this purpose, I run Tailscale inside the container in [userspace networking mode](https://tailscale.com/kb/1112/userspace-networking/). I set the following environment variables: `HTTP_PROXY=http://localhost:1055/`, `HTTPS_PROXY=https://localhost:1055/`, as well as the `K3S_URL` and `K3S_TOKEN` variables. Then I download the `k3s` binary  and execute it with `k3s agent`.

That gets me the following output:

```bash
root@74751d523fc6:/# ./k3s agent
INFO[0000] Starting k3s agent v1.27.7+k3s2 (575bce76)
INFO[0000] Adding server to load balancer k3s-agent-load-balancer: 100.81.233.65:6443
INFO[0000] Running load balancer k3s-agent-load-balancer 127.0.0.1:6444 -> [100.81.233.65:6443] [default: 100.81.233.65:6443]
ERRO[0020] failed to get CA certs: Get "https://127.0.0.1:6444/cacerts": context deadline exceeded (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
```

I'd assume this is due to the way Tailscale's userspace networking mode [handles outbound connections](https://github.com/tailscale/tailscale/issues/10267), but I'm wondering if there's any fix for this.